# Cannot add metadata to pdf

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pdf, metadata

i noticed that i am not able to add metadata to my pdf..
any clues? Here is a minimal working example. The produced pdf has no
author or title metadata. I am using miktex and texworks.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{report}

\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}
%Provides some compatiblity with latex and
%Loads the fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode, fontspec packages
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{xgreek} %Set greek hypenation and support in general


\usepackage{graphicx} %Extends the \includegraphics command
\usepackage{amsmath}  %Improoved math support e.g scalable brackets
\usepackage{array}  %Extends the array command
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz} %pgf-tikz pakcage

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}



\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,linktocpage,bookmarksopen=true,
    pdfauthor=Name,
    pdftitle={Title}
}


\begin{document}
    Hello world
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should still load `hyperref` later on in the preamble.  It is usually one of the last packages you load, if not the last one.

Comment: @jon care to explain why? Don't get me wrong, i just want to learn.

Comment: @msmechanized load `hyperref` last because `hyperref` patches all sorts of things; for example, `subfigure` defines new sorts of caption, but doesn't make them `hyperref`-aware if that might be needed.  (note, this doesn't answer your original question...)

Comment: @msmechanized -- Sure; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/8528)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the draft directive in the document class. If i remove it, title and author are displayed correctly.